# Get selected item of spinner

Tags: android-spinner

I want to insert the selected item of spinner into database when save button is pressed.
There are two spinner. One is populated from array and other is from sqlite d/b.
How can I get the string of selected item for both spinner.
My code is as below :

public class addLecture extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

```
Spinner spinner_day;
Spinner spinner_subject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_lecture);

    spinner_subject = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_subject);
    spinner_day = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_day);

    loadSpinner_subjectData();
    loadSpinner_dayData();
}


private void loadSpinner_subjectData(){
    SubjectDbHelper subjectDbHelper=new SubjectDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> spinner_name=subjectDbHelper.getSpinnerItem();

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinner_name);
    spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_subject.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);
}

private void loadSpinner_dayData(){

    String day_name[]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_dayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,day_name);
    spinner_dayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_day.setAdapter(spinner_dayAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  //not working  String label=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

 // not working   String spinner_item_day=spinner_day.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

 /*not working   SQLiteCursor subject=(SQLiteCursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String spinner_item_subject=String.valueOf(subject.getString(position));*/

  //log is not shown  Log.d("spinner",spinner_item_day);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your ItemSelectedListener, you have not specified which spinner is it listening to, so your code should look something like this:

```
spinner_day.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String selectedDay = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // or parent.getSelectedItem();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Same should be for the other spinner, try this, let me know if this does not work.